# Monorepo: Shared managed dependencies

Tags: npm, dependencies, monorepo, turborepo, npm-workspaces

I have an issue related to a monorepo (using turborepo) and NPM.
The issue is concerning dependency management and being able to manange certain dependencies that's shared with multiple apps and packages and my repo.

I've ie. this stucture

```
apps/
  project1/
    package.json
  project2/
    package.json
packages/
  project1.react/
    package.json
  project2.react/
    package.json
package.json
```

This structure is used because we want to keep all server related and data fetching in the apps, and from there import the specific page component from the corresponding `.react` folder.

In all these `package.json` we have the following dependencies

```
react
react-dom
sass
@types/node
@types/react
@types/react-dom
```

Instead of having to version-check each and single `package.json` file to ensure versions are up to date, we would like (if possible) to have a single file somewhere in the monorepo to control this.

We know this is doable inside the root `package.json` file, but we do not want to clutter that one up, but would rather have something like

```
external/
  react/
  storybook/
  graphql/
```

where we can make specific folders containing certain dependencies we from there can update and select the overall version from. And then add them as dependencies or somehow to the `package.json` files in the project.

Hopefully someone knows a good solution for this.

Kind regards,
Mads